# Converting DWG to shapefile - include annotations in the point attribute table

Tags: shapefile, annotation, dwg

I am working with a GPS system (Magnetfield system) that cannot easily export the data collected into a shapefile - it creates an individual shapefile for each point taken rather than exporting the entire job.

So, we usually export to DWG format. This creates a headache on the GIS side of things. When I try to convert the DWG to shapefile - the points collected are in one layer and the names of the points and point numbers are in the annotation layer.

Is there a way to easily add the codes and point numbers into the point layer attribute table. I don't want to have to go into the data - identify each point and create a new field and fill in each and every one, this is a big job with lots of points collected.

This seemed a lot easier when I was working with Trimble units.

I have messed around with our GPS unit and there doesn't seem to be a simple way to just export the entire job to shapefile format.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, you can convert your DWG Labels to Geodatabase Annotations first. Then convert the annotations to shapefile points. The attributes should have the labels.

Step 1: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000004169

Step 2: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009394

Answer (score 0):

- export the points from cad to a csv file
- in arcmap, import the csv file as a table
- add data and select the table which will create XY events
- export the events layer as a shapefile